# How to create dynamic multiple FilePond instances with ReactJs functional component

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I have a page where I wants to create multiple FilePond instances inside loop for each item in react js using functional component. FilePond element render successfully but when I browser file and choose then goes set to blank. Can you please check my below code and let me know what I'm missing there ? Thanks in advance!!!

{ items.map((item, index) =>

```
<div className="upload-zone">
    <FilePond
    files={files}
    onupdatefiles={setFiles}
    allowMultiple={true}
    maxFiles={3}
    name="files"
    labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
    />
</div>
```

)}

Comment: Maybe it's because they're all linked to the same state ( `files` / `setFiles` )?

Comment: @Rik Sorry for late reply but I resolved this using class component but still I don't know why it's not working with functional component ? You can see working class component example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filepond-forked-bgcqqq?file=/src/App.js
Thanks!